# raspberry pi 2 is unable to read input from PCF8591

Tags: python

I have wired according to these instructions.

http://blog.chrysocome.net/2012/12/i2c-analog-to-digital-converter.html

I tried the methods of getting the value at the bottom of the page and it told me that there was a read error. naturally, i tried a different method, python

```
#Read a value from analogue input 0
#in A/D in the PCF8591P @ address 0x48
from smbus import SMBus

bus = SMBus(1)

print("Read the A/D")
print("Ctrl C to stop")
bus.write_byte(0x48, 0) # set control register to read channel 0
last_reading =-1

while(0 == 0): # do forever
    reading = bus.read_byte(0x48) # read A/D
    if(abs(last_reading - reading) > 2):
        print(reading)
        last_reading = reading
```

that threw an error saying it to couldn't read the input. 
After several google searches, I found a fix that was simply bad wiring. I have reattached everything. still no different result. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Check with `i2cdetect` that your device is indeed being scanned. Also, the original Pis had the i2c bus as bus 0, not bus 1; maybe that's your problem?

Also, the proper way to do an infinite loop in Python is `while True:`

Comment: I did i2cdetect -y 1 and it showed up in 48.

Comment: what is the actual error?

Comment: I2cget -y 1 0x48

Comment: Error: Read Failed

Comment: I mean, what does errno contain? "read failed" is not what the OS returns.

Comment: I don't know. I'm not sure how I access that. It doesn't get printed anywhere

Comment: "errno" is the error number that system calls return. The library you are using is probably trapping the exception or return code from the read *it* is doing, and just giving you a useless message. You have the source code for the library, go in, find the actual read call, and print the actual error!